# Cделать метод, который возвращает отсутствующую цифру в строке из цифр

Tags: c#

Cделать метод, который возвращает отсутствующую цифру в строке из цифр.
В строке содержатся цифры от 1 до 9 включительно, повторений цифр нет.
Отсутствующая цифра обозначена символом '?'.

```
void Main()
{
    Debug.Assert(Foo("8372?9514") == 6, "Test 0");
    Debug.Assert(Foo("981453?67") == 2, "Test 1");
    Debug.Assert(Foo("318?92657") == 4, "Test 2");
    Debug.Assert(Foo("1234?6789") == 5, "Test 3");
    Debug.Assert(Foo("?81453267") == 9, "Test 4");

}

int Foo(string s)
{
    const int pattern = 45;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        char test = s[i];
        if(test != '?')
            result += Int32.Parse(Convert.ToString(test));
    }

    result = pattern - result;

    return result;
}
```

Решил задачу математически, не могу придумать метод для решение через работу со строкой

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, необходимо именно наткнувшись на знак вопроса попытаться определить, что он обозначает, или достаточно пробежаться по строке, и проверить наличие определённой цифры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я понял условие, попробуйте так

```
        private static void Foo(string input)
    {
            string result = "123456789";               
            Console.WriteLine(result.Except(input).FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public  class RuStack
{
    [Test]
    public  void FooTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(6, Foo("8372?9514"));
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Foo("981453?67"));
        Assert.AreEqual(4, Foo("318?92657"));
        Assert.AreEqual(5, Foo("1234?6789"));
        Assert.AreEqual(9, Foo("?81453267"));


    }

    private int Foo(string s)
    {

        for ( int index = 1; index < 10; index++)
        {
            if (!s.Contains(index.ToString())) return index;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Метод работает, но можно объяснить условия для сравнения в скобках подробнее